# Raspberry pi 2 wont show anything on screen, help?

Tags: screen

So I bought a Raspberry Pi 2 to run [SpillPass](http://www.spillmonkey.com/?page_id=169). It initially showed me a screen when plugged in via HDMI. Now the TV says no signal. According to the program cycling MAC addresses the device is cycling the MACs properly and the WiFi dongle is flashing properly. I am not sure whats wrong or what I should do. I only followed the SpillPass instructions and didn't install anything else. I don't want to unplug it because it might get damaged. The only reason this is an issue is I cannot shut the device down properly.

[Here is a link to the instructions](http://www.spillmonkey.com/?page_id=169) I followed to get it up and running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what spillpass/homepass is but does it allow SSH connections? If so you can try logging in via SSH and shutting down.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what SSH is

Comment: @Anthony SSH crash course: http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux

Comment: @Anthony Once you figured out SSH and you have a command line in front of you, here's a crash course for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNp-jPpfkc4

Answer (score 2):

most of the question is redundant - what you are running is irrelevant

your tv says "no signal", so it's not getting anything from the raspberry pi -

- check/replace your HDMI cable
- check on another TV

If the problem persists, then it may even be a dead pi hdmi circuit

Comment: It could easily be a screen saver/blanker - with no actual *fault*! 8-)

Answer (score 2):

[Secure SHell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) is, for most user, a way to access a shell ("command line interface" or CLI in some circles) on a machine across a Local or Wide Area Network.  As such, provided you have a resolvable name (a name that can be resolved into an Internet Protocol Address) or the IP address directly AND the access credentials (in simple cases often just the user-name and password) you can use the remote host as if you were typing at a keyboard and screen on it when that screen and keyboard is actually the ones on the local host you are sat at.

If you have a *nix (Linux, Free/OpenBSD, Solaris, MacOS X) PC all you need to run is something like `ssh pi@192.168.1.2` however the complication is that you may not know that `192.168.1.2` IS the address (it probably ISN'T) for you to use.  To obtain that, one way is to run the `nmap` (network map) command with arguments to search your Local Area Network, and filter the results to get the one that matches the range of [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) (Hardware address) assigned to the Wired Ethernet Port on the RPi.  One way is using the `awk` command:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24 | awk '/^Nmap/{ip=$NF}/B8:27:EB/{print ip}'
```

on your PC - I don't have a Pi up and running now but the output should be obvious.

As of Windows 10 Microsoft has not got a native equivalent to SSH (As Far As I Know!) but there is a well known Free and Open Source solution in the form of [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)<sup>("It makes windows usable!")</sup> which when run in a Windows GUI, will create the equivalent to a text screen on the remote host.  You will still have the issue of finding the IP address to use (though you *may* get somewhere with `raspberry.local` if Zeroconf/Bonjour is in use on the PC and the RPi.)

Assuming that you can get a SSH link running to the RPi for the first time you may get a warning that the remote machine's (the RPi) finger print is not recognised/known - this is to be expected - you will need to respond with `yes` to proceed - then you will be presented with a username then password prompts - unless you have changed them the defaults of `pi` and `raspberry` will be what you need to get in so that you can issue the `shutdown -h -P now` command before waiting say 45 seconds to allow everything to finish before removing the power...

Comment: Well typing in the IP address in my browser brings me to an interface that lets me change macs and such for the device. However it does not let me type any commands for the device. The only way I can type commands is via the tv, I might be able to do something via the SD card but I have no idea if removing it will cause issues sense it is running a process

Comment: @SlySven See [my comment on PandaLion98's answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40629/raspberry-pi-2-wont-show-anything-on-screen-help/40652#comment57730_40652).

Comment: **Don't remove the card whilst the Pi is powered up!** - You risk corrupting any files that are open and given that usually there are files that are open all the time (though there are distributions / workarounds that minimise or eliminate that) in normal cases this is likely to cause problems afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

### Overly-simplified beginner-friendly SSH tutorial/crash course (Windows):

**What is SSH?**

- SSH, or **S**ecure **SH**ell, is a way to use the command-line interface over the network.

**Wait. What's a command line?**

- A command-line interface is a way to tell a computer what to do. The difference is instead of the usual *point-your-cursor-then-click* (called a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)), you type in the commands instead.

**Okay, got it. Now how do I connect to the machine via SSH?**

- For Windows, you should go get [`putty`(direct link)](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe)
- For Linux or OSX, you don't have to download anything. They can already use SSH.

**Looks scary. How do I use this?**

- I'll be straightforward here. If you are a complete beginner, simply enter the IP address and click `Open`

[image]

---

**It's asking for login details. Help**

- Unfortunately, I have no idea what username/password you should use for SpillPass. Try using `pi` as the username and `raspberry` as the password.
- While you're typing your password, you shouldn't see anything happening (no asterisk***, nothing). This is perfectly normal.

**Ooh. I see a terminal. Wait. Is this it?**

- If you can see `pi@[IP address or something] ~ $`, then congratulations. You're looking at a terminal (another term for command-line interface).
- Try typing `apt-get moo` and then press enter. If you see something, congratulations. Your Pi is not broken.

---

### Additional points

**Can I turn off my Pi? OMG, it might get broken.**

- It won't break*

**Why did my screen go blank? What's happening?!**

- It might be saving power. Sort of like when your computer monitor turns off after a while.
- Try attaching a mouse or keyboard then press something. The monitor or TV should be back on again.

Comment: It have been much better if you had written a self-answered Q&A about using SSH from windows and placed a link in a comment.  Since the OP isn't using default Raspbian, there's no reason to believe `sshd` is even running, which would mean this answer has nothing to do with the question...

Comment: However, there is a brief reference to using putty and ssh [here](http://www.spillmonkey.com/?page_id=169), so presumably it is running. :)